# kendoui autocomplete with json

Tags: autocomplete

I am having some problems with kendo auto complete  my json data set is like

```
       [{"clientname":"Niyazi"},{"clientname":"uzman"}]
```

and this is my code block. when I use server filtering it is becoming undefined undefied undefined. also if I dont use autocomplete does not opens . dont know where I do wrong

```
$("#clients").kendoAutoComplete({
     minLength: 3,
   dataTextField: "clientname", // JSON property name to use
 dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
   type: 'json',

 pageSize: 10, // limits result set
 transport: {
read: {
    url:"<?=site_url('clients/json_client_list');?>",
     data: {
  q: function(){
   return $("#clients").data("kendoAutoComplete").value();
  },
 }


  }},
schema: {
                             clientname: "clientname"
                        },
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

dataType : 'json',  forgot to mentin data type therefore.. it was not working.